# AttributeError: module 'transformers' has no attribute 'BertTokenizerFast'

Tags: python, pip, spacy

I have installed spacy onto a Jupyter Notebook in Jupyter Lab that I access through the Anaconda Navigator, all on a remote desktop.

I was able to install spacy using

```
!pip install spacy
```

But when I tried to run

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

I got a common OSError 50 that 'en_core_web_sm' was not a Python package. So I went in circles for a while and finally downloaded en_core_web_sm 3.7.0 to my Downloads folder from [here](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.7.0) and then used

```
!pip install Downloads/en_core_web_sm-3.7.0.tar.gz
```

to install the english language model. I used `!pip list` and confirmed that I am using `en-core-web-sm 3.7.0` and `spacy 3.7.2` and when I tried to load that model, I got this weird attribute error:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py:51, in load(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
     27 def load(
     28     name: Union[str, Path],
     29     *,
   (...)
     34     config: Union[Dict[str, Any], Config] = util.SimpleFrozenDict(),
     35 ) -> Language:
     36     """Load a spaCy model from an installed package or a local path.
     37 
     38     name (str): Package name or model path.
   (...)
     49     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     50     """
---> 51     return util.load_model(
     52         name,
     53         vocab=vocab,
     54         disable=disable,
     55         enable=enable,
     56         exclude=exclude,
     57         config=config,
     58     )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy\util.py:465, in load_model(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
    463     return get_lang_class(name.replace("blank:", ""))()
    464 if is_package(name):  # installed as package
--> 465     return load_model_from_package(name, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    466 if Path(name).exists():  # path to model data directory
    467     return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy\util.py:501, in load_model_from_package(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
    484 """Load a model from an installed package.
    485 
    486 name (str): The package name.
   (...)
    498 RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
    499 """
    500 cls = importlib.import_module(name)
--> 501 return cls.load(vocab=vocab, disable=disable, enable=enable, exclude=exclude, config=config)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\__init__.py:10, in load(**overrides)
      9 def load(**overrides):
---> 10     return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy\util.py:682, in load_model_from_init_py(init_file, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
    680 if not model_path.exists():
    681     raise IOError(Errors.E052.format(path=data_path))
--> 682 return load_model_from_path(
    683     data_path,
    684     vocab=vocab,
    685     meta=meta,
    686     disable=disable,
    687     enable=enable,
    688     exclude=exclude,
    689     config=config,
    690 )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy\util.py:539, in load_model_from_path(model_path, meta, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
    537 overrides = dict_to_dot(config, for_overrides=True)
    538 config = load_config(config_path, overrides=overrides)
--> 539 nlp = load_model_from_config(
    540     config,
    541     vocab=vocab,
    542     disable=disable,
    543     enable=enable,
    544     exclude=exclude,
    545     meta=meta,
    546 )
    547 return nlp.from_disk(model_path, exclude=exclude, overrides=overrides)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy\util.py:587, in load_model_from_config(config, meta, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, auto_fill, validate)
    584 # This will automatically handle all codes registered via the languages
    585 # registry, including custom subclasses provided via entry points
    586 lang_cls = get_lang_class(nlp_config["lang"])
--> 587 nlp = lang_cls.from_config(
    588     config,
    589     vocab=vocab,
    590     disable=disable,
    591     enable=enable,
    592     exclude=exclude,
    593     auto_fill=auto_fill,
    594     validate=validate,
    595     meta=meta,
    596 )
    597 return nlp

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy\language.py:1830, in Language.from_config(cls, config, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, meta, auto_fill, validate)
   1824 warn_if_jupyter_cupy()
   1826 # Note that we don't load vectors here, instead they get loaded explicitly
   1827 # inside stuff like the spacy train function. If we loaded them here,
   1828 # then we would load them twice at runtime: once when we make from config,
   1829 # and then again when we load from disk.
-> 1830 nlp = lang_cls(
   1831     vocab=vocab,
   1832     create_tokenizer=create_tokenizer,
   1833     create_vectors=create_vectors,
   1834     meta=meta,
   1835 )
   1836 if after_creation is not None:
   1837     nlp = after_creation(nlp)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy\language.py:188, in Language.__init__(self, vocab, max_length, meta, create_tokenizer, create_vectors, batch_size, **kwargs)
    166 """Initialise a Language object.
    167 
    168 vocab (Vocab): A `Vocab` object. If `True`, a vocab is created.
   (...)
    183 DOCS: https://spacy.io/api/language#init
    184 """
    185 # We're only calling this to import all factories provided via entry
    186 # points. The factory decorator applied to these functions takes care
    187 # of the rest.
--> 188 util.registry._entry_point_factories.get_all()
    190 self._config = DEFAULT_CONFIG.merge(self.default_config)
    191 self._meta = dict(meta)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\catalogue\__init__.py:110, in Registry.get_all(self)
    108 result = {}
    109 if self.entry_points:
--> 110     result.update(self.get_entry_points())
    111 for keys, value in REGISTRY.copy().items():
    112     if len(self.namespace) == len(keys) - 1 and all(
    113         self.namespace[i] == keys[i] for i in range(len(self.namespace))
    114     ):

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\catalogue\__init__.py:125, in Registry.get_entry_points(self)
    123 result = {}
    124 for entry_point in self._get_entry_points():
--> 125     result[entry_point.name] = entry_point.load()
    126 return result

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py:202, in EntryPoint.load(self)
    197 """Load the entry point from its definition. If only a module
    198 is indicated by the value, return that module. Otherwise,
    199 return the named object.
    200 """
    201 match = self.pattern.match(self.value)
--> 202 module = import_module(match.group('module'))
    203 attrs = filter(None, (match.group('attr') or '').split('.'))
    204 return functools.reduce(getattr, attrs, module)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
    124             break
    125         level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1204, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1176, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1204, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1176, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:690, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:940, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy_curated_transformers\pipeline\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .transformer import CuratedTransformer

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy_curated_transformers\pipeline\transformer.py:26
     23 from thinc.types import Ragged
     25 from ..errors import Errors
---> 26 from ..models.listeners import ListenerStateUtils
     27 from ..models.output import DocTransformerOutput, TransformerModelOutput
     28 from ..models.types import TransformerListenerModelT

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy_curated_transformers\models\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .architectures import (
      2     build_albert_transformer_model_v1,
      3     build_bert_transformer_model_v1,
      4     build_camembert_transformer_model_v1,
      5     build_roberta_transformer_model_v1,
      6     build_xlmr_transformer_model_v1,
      7     build_pytorch_checkpoint_loader_v1,
      8 )
      9 from .hf_loader import build_hf_transformer_encoder_loader_v1
     10 from .scalar_weight import build_scalar_weight_v1

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy_curated_transformers\models\architectures.py:32
     29 from thinc.types import ArgsKwargs, Floats2d, Ints1d
     31 from ..errors import Errors
---> 32 from ..tokenization.types import Tok2PiecesModelT
     33 from .listeners import (
     34     WrappedTransformerAndListener,
     35     replace_listener_callback,
     36     replace_listener_cfg_callback,
     37 )
     38 from .output import TransformerModelOutput

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy_curated_transformers\tokenization\__init__.py:3
      1 from .bbpe_encoder import build_byte_bpe_encoder_loader_v1, build_byte_bpe_encoder_v1
      2 from .char_encoder import build_char_encoder_loader_v1, build_char_encoder_v1
----> 3 from .hf_loader import build_hf_piece_encoder_loader_v1
      4 from .sentencepiece_encoder import (
      5     build_camembert_sentencepiece_encoder_v1,
      6     build_sentencepiece_encoder_loader_v1,
      7     build_sentencepiece_encoder_v1,
      8     build_xlmr_sentencepiece_encoder_v1,
      9 )
     10 from .wordpiece_encoder import (
     11     build_bert_wordpiece_encoder_v1,
     12     build_wordpiece_encoder_loader_v1,
     13     build_wordpiece_encoder_v1,
     14 )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\spacy_curated_transformers\tokenization\hf_loader.py:17
     13 from ..errors import Errors
     15 if has_hf_transformers:
     16     SUPPORTED_TOKENIZERS = (
---> 17         transformers.BertTokenizerFast,
     18         transformers.RobertaTokenizerFast,
     19         transformers.XLMRobertaTokenizerFast,
     20         transformers.CamembertTokenizerFast,
     21         transformers.BertJapaneseTokenizer,
     22     )
     23 else:
     24     SUPPORTED_TOKENIZERS = ()  # type: ignore

AttributeError: module 'transformers' has no attribute 'BertTokenizerFast'
```

Comment: Try downgrading `spacy` to 3.6.1 with: `pip install spacy==3.6.1` and then try `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Feel free to post that as an answer and I can accept it. Also, how did you know to do that? I've been trying to figure this out for ~3 hours.

Comment: I appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: I encountered these types of errors before and tried to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading `spacy` to 3.6.1 with:

```
pip install spacy==3.6.1
```

and then try

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

Comment: for some reason now I am getting a RegistryError `[E892] Unknown function registry: 'vectors'` when I try to run `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm)`. Any ideas about fixing that?

Comment: I downgraded `en_core_web_sm` to 3.6.0 and that worked